# Ошибка. Повторите попытку позже

Tags: google-chrome, youtube, opera

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Adobe Flash обновлял , кэш очищал, обновлял страницу по 100 раз, ничего не помогает
И так на ВСЕХ браузерах . Даже если и удастся загрузить страницу нормально, без ошибок, то видео будет грузиться кучу времени. Хотя скорость моего интернета приемлемая(80-90mbps)+ иногда страницы открываются как будто их код перевернули и удалили половину . Месиво из надписей, картинок и ссылок
Я плохо разбираюсь в этом, без помощи не протяну

Comment: Может это связано с недавними сбоями youtube по всему миру

Comment: Не волнуйтесь, это ютуб сбои, это у всёх.

Answer (score 0):

Удали обновление "Обновлени безопасности для Microsoft Windows (KB4586793)" от 11.11.20

Comment: давайте пожалуйста более развёрнутые ответы